# What are the pros and cons attaching TDE enabled .mdf to SqlLocalDb?

Tags: sql, sql-server, localdb, tde

I am thinking to attach TDE-enabled `.mdf` files to `SqlLocalDb`. Before investing time in it, I want to know whether it is worth doing that? So need some helpful suggestions.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250175/what-are-impacts-of-tde-enabling-on-database-performance) may be of some use to you.

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what you want to do: why do you think you need to use TDE? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Without that information, no one can tell you if it's a good idea or not.

Comment: It would likely violate the LocalDB license, since it is working around the technical limitation of SQL Server Express edition which is not allowed by the license (disclaimer: I'm not a lawyer).